# Router: use LAN port as WAN port

Tags: lan, vlan, wan, adsl-router

*Initially asked at https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/75891/router-use-lan-port-as-wan-port but [was sent](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/75891/router-use-lan-port-as-wan-port#comment135384_75891) to Super User. There with screenshots. Here don't have 10 reputation — can't post images.*

For a home internet, I am currently switching from `ADSL` ISP to optical fibre ISP. The fibre ISP consultants say that my `ADSL` modem-and-router can not be used in their network, so I need to acquire a new router (that will get the internet from fibre media converter).

My `ADSL` modem-and-router is `ZTE ZXHN H108N`, apparently flashed with my [ISP](https://ukrtelecom.ua/)'s custom firmware; the fibre ISP's buy-from-us is [Netis W1](https://www.netis-systems.com/Home/detail/id/137.html)

I wonder whether an `ADSL` modem-and-router is actually useless in this case.

[[HOWTO] TURN A LAN PORT INTO A WAN PORT!! [Linksys E900 Wireless Router]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QLcAl0O4gG0)
The video in short: `LAN` ports and `WAN` port belong to 2 different `VLAN`s. By assigning a `LAN` port to the same `VLAN` as `WAN`, you turn the `LAN` port into a `WAN` port.

> -Only Broadcom based devices support port-based VLAN's

> [ZTE ZXHN H108N is ADSL/ADSL2+ Wi-Fi router based on Broadcom 6328.](https://openwrt.org/toh/zte/zxhnh108n)

So, my question is: on my `ADSL` modem-and-router `ZTE ZXHN H108N`, if I change the `VLAN` of a `LAN` port from `1` to `0`, can I use it as a fully functional router connecting me to the fibre internet (can't check it myself now — the ordered fibre internet is underway).

Also, if yes, then will [a crossover cable be required instead of straight-through](https://forums.anandtech.com/threads/when-to-use-a-crossover-cable-from-modem-to-router.670785/post-2912697)?

I am a lay-user of networkware, please speak to me in plain English

```
> telnet 192.168.1.1
Trying 192.168.1.1...
Connected to 192.168.1.1.
Escape character is '^]'.

Password: *****
Copyright (c) 2012 - 2015 ZTE Corporation
ZTE> show wan status
PVC-0 
        Status = Up
        Ip = 94.179.153.74
PVC-1 
        Status = Up
PVC-2 
        Status = Down
PVC-3 
        Status = Down
PVC-4 
        Status = Down
PVC-5 
        Status = Down
PVC-6 
        Status = Down
PVC-7 
        Status = Down
```

The accepted answers https://superuser.com/a/1068435/1250598 and https://superuser.com/a/1245737/1250598 on similar questions contradict each other. Clarifications are welcome

Comment: They contradict with each other because 1) the first answer seems flat out wrong ("ADSL router, not a modem"?? if it has ADSL it is _literally_ a modem) and 2) there is _great_ variety between home routers/gateways, as they usually don't offer VLANs as a user-facing feature so it might exist or it might not, sometimes even in different HW revisions of seemingly the same model.

Comment: Also, PVCs are specifically an ADSL/ATM term. (They're kiiinda like VLANs but for the ADSL side, not for Ethernet.) So that means the `show wan` command is about ADSL only, and isn't what you're looking for in general.

Comment: It wont help here  but you would use a passthru cable when connecting to a switch or router. (if port is gigabit it can ve either as gigabit autonegotiates crossover)

Comment: The router should be capable of this with terminal access by moving one of the switch ports into the WAN vLAN _(the switch ports are usually numbered differently than the numbering on the back of the router)_. This should be accessible within the network config file _(unsure of location in ZTE firmware, check `/etc`)_ or by using a switch config program, such as `swconfig` _(ZTE may not use that program, so look in `/bin`, `/sbin`, `/usr/bin`, & `/usr/sbin`)_. General FYI, `telnet` is not secure and there is no way to secure it, as it passes everything in plaintext, incl. root's passphrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear that this will work  although it is possible-probable even that a skilled expert could make it work.

I cant speak to this specific router  but it if the device can run openwrt it can very likely be configured to convert a lan port into a WAN port, and likely by way ofsetting the ports up to connect to the chip using different vlans on the chip -> untagged ports on the "switch" side if the port. (I have done this on openwrt - albeit many years ago)

That said  its high risk and not something I would consider worthwhile.  Ethernet routers are dirt cheap, and (last I looked) openwrt was not user friendly - unless you happen to be a linux system admin by trade - which I am -  Even then  dd-wrt (which is unlikely to work on your dsl device) is way easier as it has a GUI you can do most things through.

Unless you are bloody minded, more interested in what makes the router tick  or your time has no value,  just spend $50 or olso on an ethernet router you can flash with dd-wrt. (That you mention you are a lay user of networkware means you are moderately likely to just brick your router and end up sad and frustrated)

Comment: OpenWrt supports the ZTE [H108N](https://openwrt.org/toh/zte/zxhnh108n), with the caveat [DSL won't be functional](https://openwrt.org/unsupported/dsl_modem) due to [Broadcom's](https://openwrt.org/meta/infobox/broadcom_dsl) BCM63281 DSL [chipset](https://openwrt.org/docs/techref/hardware/soc/soc.broadcom.bcm63xx)